# R loop for barplots how to pass on data?

Tags: r, loops, plot

I need to produce and save to jpeg multiple simple barplots, with four bars representing four data points. I've succeeded in getting the code to loop, producing the correct number of jpeg file barplots in the desired format. BUT I cannot work out what code is necessary to insert the relevant data for each barplot. I can only produce multiple plots with the same data represented in each file/plot. **What should I change in my code to insert the relevant data into each plot?**

Below is the code I have.

'names' is a dataframe containing one variable named 'personid'. 'personid' contains all the variable names in 'mydata'.

'mydata' is a dataframe set up like this:

```
  J5A J5B J5C ...
w 2.1 1.3 3.2 ...
x 1.9 2.2 1.8 ...
y 1.5 2.4 1.8 ...
z 1.9 2.2 1.7 ...
```

If I use a variable name (eg mydata$J5A) in the code, I can produce 43 plots in separate jpeg files that all contain the data for J5A. Not good. My understanding is that I should use mydata$kid.i, but obviously not, because the loop aborts and I get error

```
"Error in barplot.default(kid.i, xlab = "Language Skills", ylim = c(1,  : 
'height' must be a vector or a matrix"
```

Code:

```
allkids <- unique(names$personid)
for (i in 1 : 43) {
setwd("D:/R/BARPLOTS/")
kid.i <- allkids[i]
filename <- paste (kid.i, ".jpg", sep="")
jpeg(file = filename)
barplot(mydata$J5A, xlab = "Language Skills", ylim = c(1,3), xpd = FALSE,
    names.arg=working2$varname, axes=FALSE, cex.names=.8, col=c("darkblue","red",
    "darkgreen", "yellow"))
dev.off()
}
```

**UPDATE:** For those interested, here is the final working code with bugs removed:

```
allkids <- unique(names$personid)
for (i in 2 : 44) {
setwd("D:/R/BARPLOTS/")
kid.i <- allkids[i]
filename <- paste (kid.i, ".jpg", sep="")
jpeg(file = filename)
barplot(mydata[, i], xlab = "Language Skills", ylim = c(1,3), xpd = FALSE,
    names.arg=working2$varname, axes=FALSE, cex.names=.8, col=c("darkblue","red",
    "darkgreen", "yellow"))
dev.off()
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are pretty close!  the culprit is here:  `barplot(mydata$J5A ....`
you instead want to use

```
  barplot(mydata[, i] . . .. .
```

---

---

**What gave it away** is that the first argument to `barplot` is of course the data.  So we look at that argument and see if it varies with each iteration of your for loop.  `mydata$J5A` is constant, and we need instead some reference to `i`, such as `mydata[, i]`

**Update as per comments**
If your first column is (or first few columns are) not data that you want to plot -- for example labels, names, other features -- then you should have your iterating variable, `i`, start after that column.  In the specific case shown above, you want to use

```
  for (i in 2:ncol(myData))  {
    . . . 
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for this - I tried it but when I substitute      mydata$J5A    for    mydata[, i]     I get the same error message as when I substitute mydata$kid.i, which is: Error in barplot.default(mydata[, i], xlab = "Language Skills", ylim = c(1,  : 
  'height' must be a vector or a matrix

Comment: can you run `dput(head(myData))` and paste the output into your question above

Comment: @miggy_ad,  Try starting `i` at `2` instead of 1.  (see the update to the answer above)

Comment: NB for other readers: dput(head(myData)) output was removed after problem solved, to keep thread clean